# Industrial or Odd Percussion Creation

Tags: sound-design, drum

I could be totally wrong about what it is called. Good examples are in Skrillex "Fire Away"

Starts at 1:10 barely, full, and clear at 1:20
Comes in with main drums at around 2:07
Morphed somewhat at 3:50 hear it (low passed) clearly without most everything else dropped out

It evolves and changes somewhat throughout the track.

It's just odd percussion blips and cracks (I don't know), industrial maybe?

I just want to know how you go about making those types of sounds.

We're oscillators used or just noise?
Any tutorials?

Please don't say, "sounds like FM use that..." If a phrase like that would solve my problem I would be smart enough to not need to be told it, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That track kind of has a chillstep vibe. The drums at first sound like a bit of sampled percussion that may not be drums but rather found sound stuff like cameras and things. It's more glitch or idm style than industrial. Look at using sounds for percussion that do not come from music but make interesting percussive sounds. When the track gets going the drums sound like pitched up breaks, traditional drums that are pitched up, filtered, and saturated to taste and doing that double time 140 chillstep thing.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations to where I could find high quality samples of this variety?

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: get SonicCouture's Konkrete 3 and Heavyocity's Damage. Both chock-full of very unusual kits with those types of sounds that aren't just raw samples, but have a lot of thoughtful programming behind them (such as velocity-switching for nuances when you play softer). Actually, Native Instruments Battery 4 has a "Berlin Office" kit with many of those found sounds as well... and others that may be suitable.

The reality of the beast is that you can hit random things in your house and end up with related vibes.

Here, it's not just about the samples but effects treatments — play drum loops through Diego Stocco's Rhythmic Convolutions http://www.diegostocco.com/ffs-rhythmic-convolutions/ and can end up sounding very warbly/crunchy and crackly.

For even more extreme percussion of the sort, listen to Amon Tobin's ISAM (all of it: it's mandatory fun, and I don't just mean that in a Weird Al way) and some of Eskmo's stuff. We may make a crumbly snare/clap addict outta you yet...

The usual "experiment and use your ears" applies but this should give you a clear direction to head in. :3

Answer (score -2):

In my experience industrial sounds are usually wrote in a weird kind of odd harmonics. What I use is disharmonic fm then I put a reeverb on it. XD

It works for me man.

Then mess around with the bpm in honour of the homemade fm greatness.